# check if a given library with a given version is installed

Tags: build, makefile, cmake, version

What is the simplest and most practical way to check if on a given system all the libraries that a given source will need are installed together with the headers ?

The **library version** must also *mandatory* being checked, and in case of a library that is too new or too old a warning or an error must be thrown or even better the correct version installed automatically !

How can this be done in Cmake or with normal Makefiles ?

Comment: Have you tried checking the cmake documentation?

Comment: It depends on the `FindXXX.cmake` provided module which is not standardized and may or may not support such functionality. AFAIK the easiest way to implement it is config mode of find_package: [example](https://github.com/forexample/package-example)